# Extract a link from an API response in python

Tags: python, regex, string, api

I am new to using API's and I need some help. The API returns a few different strings but I only want to extract the link it returns. I've heard that it can be done with regex but I'm not sure how to use it.

`print(response.text)` provides the following output:

```
{"link":"https:\/\/cdn02.ytjar.xyz\/get.php\/6\/29\/UxxajLWwzqY.mp3?h=pJErEk75Q8zJ0GhlF-5sFQ&s=1635898224&n=Icona-Pop-I-Love-It-feat-Charli-XCX-OFFICIAL-VIDEO","title":"Icona Pop - I Love It (feat. Charli XCX) [OFFICIAL VIDEO]","progress":0,"duration":180.03591959124,"status":"ok","msg":"success"}
```

I just want to assign the link to a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `json` module to extract the link:

```
import json

resp_json = json.loads(response.text) # or response.json() if using requests lib
link = resp_json["link"]
print (f'The link is: {link}')
```

Comment: @JonathanLangford you are welcome. Also note that if you are using the `requests` library, each response comes with a `.json()` method which you can also call to give you the json